# Switching setpoints of a low voltage monitor

Tags: voltage-measurement

I'd like to build a low-voltage monitor that is adjustable by flipping a switch to one of two setpoints. There are plenty of sample circuits, below is  one adapted from [here](http://www.eleccircuit.com/low-voltage-battery-monitor-by-lm339/)

I'd adjust the R2 and R3 to the setpoints I'm interested in, and then use SW1 to choose which one to use.

My question is, since SW1 will be located off board, plugged into a socket, and possibly a meter or two away from the circuit, will this cause inaccuracy in the circuit setpoints (i.e from varying resistance of the switch contacts, noise in the wires, resistance in the socket the cable plugs into, etc)?

Would I be better off using 2 comparators, each connected directly to its own potentiometer and using the switch to chose between the outputs of the two?

I'm not necessarily set on using this circuit, if there's a more appropriate monitoring IC or other circuit that would work better, I'm open to options.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fCtM5s.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: The LM339 you propose using is an analog comparator, not an op-amp - however, it is the appropriate thing to use in this application. (Many beginners want to use an op-amp where a comparator would be more appropriate.)

Comment: Thanks,I've been looking at so many circuits using opamps and comparators, and that I called it the wrong name (even though I know they are [different](http://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/90657/what-is-the-difference-between-opamp-and-comparator). I edited my question to call it by the correct name.

Comment: Depending on required accuracy, you may be just fine with twisted wires or three pieces of cheap coaxial cable. The center conductor would carry the analog voltage, the shield would be attached to circuit ground. Add a capacitor (say 220nF) from V+ to ground to suppress noise.

Answer (score 1):

SW1 (as shown in your diagram) could be an analogue switch - this is a chip that does what it says on the can - it can switch an analogue signal through its circuit or it can go "open circuit" just like an electromagnetic relay. You could of course use a relay and activate it on and off remotely but it might not be as relaible as the analogue switch after a few years of use.

Why use an analogue switch - it has a digital input that controls the position of the switch and this means it can be fed remotely from a digital signal - noise that might appear on the digital line to the analogue switch would have to be pretty big to activate the switch incorrectly and this is benefit. You were worried about: -

> Resistance of the switch contacts, noise in the wires, resistance in
>   the socket the cable plugs into, etc

And to a great degree using an analogue switch overcomes this. There are plenty to choose from just google "analogue switch". I just did and top of the list was the [ADG5423](http://www.analog.com/en/switchesmultiplexers/analog-switches/adg5423/products/product.html?gclid=CJSzndayz7wCFVDLtAodWDEAZg) - I'm not saying it's ideal - I'm saying they are easy to locate from all the main suppliers. Here's what it does: -

[image]

Note that this one has a normally closed contact (sw2) and a normally open contact (sw1). It has an on-resistance of 13.5 ohms but that shouldn't be a worry because you aren't passing any current to drop any voltage. If you were you can find devices with sub-1ohm on resistance.

Comment: Thanks, that's an interesting solution and looks like Maxim has some models available with through-hole mounting rather than surface mount and only cost $1 or $2 so it's definitely an affordable solution. Though I still wonder if it's better to switch the voltage divider, or use 2 circuits and switch the output.

Answer (score 0):

The general idea is fine, but there are a few details. Contact resistance is not a problem, since the input impedance of the 339 is high. Noise and AC pickup are a big problem. Use a resistor/capacitor (like 10k / .1 uF) in front of the 339 to filter your input. Also, you need some hysteresis to keep the LED from flickering when the voltage is near the trip level. In this case, from the new RC filter, connect a 1K to the + input, and a 1Meg from the output to the + input. A 0.1 uF cap across the zener won't hurt, either.